# TSQL - Calculate difference between values from yesterday to today, SELF JOIN question

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have pieced together code from various answers online to get the result I want but, I don't understand why it's working and I would like to know what the JOIN is actually doing where it says RowNum + 1.

The original problem is to calculate the percentage difference between a value from yesterday to today.  I'm a little fuzzy on Self Joins, but I do understand self join.  When I add the RowNum column, that confuses me.

---

**Question**

What is T2.RowNum = T1.RowNum + 1 doing in the self join please?

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t1

CREATE TABLE #T1 (
ProductTotal int
,CountDate date
)

INSERT INTO #t1
VALUES 
       (893911,'20200815')
      ,(888970,'20200816')
      ,(899999,'20200817')
      

WITH cte AS (
SELECT 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CountDate) AS RowNum
,ProductTotal
,CountDate
FROM #t1
WHERE   CountDate > CAST(GETDATE () - 2 AS DATE)
)
SELECT 
    t1.RowNum
   ,t1.ProductTotal   
   ,CAST(((t1.ProductTotal - t2.ProductTotal) * 1.0 / t2.ProductTotal) * 100 AS DECIMAL(10,2))  AS ProductDiff
   ,t1.CountDate
FROM cte AS t1
LEFT JOIN cte t2 ON T2.RowNum = T1.RowNum + 1
```

Comment: What part is it you don't understand here? What `ROW_NUMBER` does, or how `T2.RowNum = T1.RowNum + 1` works? Personally, however, rather than a Self Join I would simply use the `LAG` or `LEAD` functions, which lowers the number of scans from 2 to 1.

Comment: Hi @Larnu, I understand how Row_Number works, I don't understand how T2.RowNum = T1.RowNum + 1 works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have values on each day, a better approach uses `lag()`:

```
SELECT ProductTotal, CountDate,
       (ProductTotal - prev_ProductTotal) * 1.0 / ProductTotal
FROM (SELECT t.*, 
             LAG(ProductTotal) OVER (ORDER BY CountDate) as prev_ProductTotal
      FROM #t1 t
     ) t
WHERE CountDate > CAST(GETDATE () - 1 AS DATE)
```

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff.  I've not seen this structure before.  What does t.* reference / do in the subquery in the FROM clause please?

Comment: To all looking at this question, Gordon answered what ultimately need to be done (change the logic) and Larnu answered the specific question.

Answer (score 2):

Note, that, as I commented, I completely agree with Gordon here, and that `LAG` (or `LEAD`) is the right answer here. To explain what you ask in the comment *"I don't understand how T2.RowNum = T1.RowNum + 1 works*":

A `JOIN` returns rows where the expression in the `ON` is true. As you have an `INNER JOIN` then only rows from both sides of the `JOIN` where the expression evaluates to True are displayed. For a `LEFT JOIN` any prior previously returned would not be "lost". (There are other types of joins too.)

For `T2.RowNum = T1.RowNum + 1` this is basic maths. `2` is matched to `1` (`1+1`), `3` is match to `2` (`2+1`)... `100` is matched to `99` (`99 + 1`). So the data from `T1` is matched to the row "after" in terms of the `ROW_NUMBER` order defined within the CTE. In this case, that would be the row with the "next" value for `CountDate` in ascending order.